# DFA for (0001)*, is it correct

Tags: finite-automata, computation-theory, dfa, formal-languages

PLease check whether this dfa is correct or not?
Thankyou[image: Finite Automata]

Comment: What does the transition at the top of the diagram mean?  Which states are accepting?

Comment: the first state is starting and final state.

Comment: Then it's correct other than the unexplained top link.

Comment: Also, depending on your definition of DFA, you might be missing a dead state and around five transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not the correct one. see below image. it is a correct DFA.

[image]